# I want to send the username of the person submitting the form along with form data

Tags: forms

I wanted to know how to get the username for whoever submits a form so I can pass it to `db_insert` along with form data.

Sorry, I'm new to Drupal and php. I'm just try to learn.

Yes, it is custom code. Here is the form. I have based it on tutorials I've found so far.

```
function input_simple_form($form, &$form_submit) {

$form['color'] = array(
    '#title' => t('color:'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
            '#description' => t('What is your favorite color?'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">', 
    '#suffix' => '</div><br>',
    );
$form['TV_Show'] = array(
    '#title' => t('TV_Show:'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('What is favorite TV show?'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">', 
    '#suffix' => '</div><br>',
    );

$form['input'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#submit' => array('input_simple_form_submit'),
    );

return $form;   
}
```

Then I send the data to database:

```
function input_simple_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

// Display a message upon successful submission.
drupal_set_message(t("Added @color @TV_Show", array('@color' => $form_state['values']['color'], '@Name' => $form_state['values']['TV_Show'])));
$id = db_insert("TestForm")
->fields(array(
    'color' => $form_state['values']['color'],      
    'TV_Show' => $form_state['values']['TV_Show'],
    'SubmitBy' => $user->name,
    ))
->execute();
}
```

I'm not sure how to pass `$user` to the submit function. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why would you need that? It will be the same as username of currently logged in user, and that's pretty readily available, no need to pass it in form.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, but you didn't show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Note that to get the proper way to get the username if the format_username() function (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_username/7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* pass `$user` to the submit function.

Instead, you add a declaration of the global `$user` object to the start of the submit function to bring it into scope.  Like this:

```
function input_simple_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;

  // Display a message upon successful submission.
  drupal_set_message(t("Added @color @TV_Show", array(
    '@color' => $form_state['values']['color'],
    '@Name' => $form_state['values']['TV_Show'],
  )));
  $id = db_insert("TestForm")
    ->fields(array(
      'color' => $form_state['values']['color'],        
      'TV_Show' => $form_state['values']['TV_Show'],
      'SubmitBy' => $user->name,
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the user object using global keyword:

```
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
$username = $user->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom code, you need to use

```
global $user;
$username = $user->name;
```

Regards,

K.